# jquery val returning object instead of string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is the first time I have faced this particular issue. I have been using the .val() method very often but it has never returned an object. Here's the jquery code for this section:

```
    $("#ResidentialLocationStateList").change(function () {
    url = "/ResidentialBuilding/getCityList?=state";
    state = $("#ResidentialLocationStateList").val();
    url = url + state;
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The ResidentialLocationStateList is a multiple select dropdown menu. When I try to make a JSON call, an empty array is returned (which i know is wrong).

A console.log() of state reveals something of this kind

["AZ"] as opposed to just a string.

Any idea whats going on here?

**UPDATE**

Here's the html markup. The cities that are retrieved from the AJAX call will be populated inside the checkboxes div using a checkbox.

Comment: Can you give some html to go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal since you have a *multiple select dropdown*. Since you can have more than 1 result, jQuery return a array of selected options. You can use join to have a string :

```
url = url + state.join(',');
```

Or if you want a single result :

```
url = url + state[0]; //This will fail if no option are selected
```

Comment: The multiple select is only for displaying purpose. The functionality only works when a single state is selected...

Comment: Still, if you use a multiple selected, the returned value will be an array. You either need to use a single select or the solution above.

Comment: Apparently, it seems that my url was incorrect. I fixed the URL and everything seems to be working fine. Weird.